# Delete button code sometimes working

Tags: vb.net

How to debug the following code?

```
Dim deleteok As String = MsgBox("Do you really want to delete this record", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "updating records")
        If vbYes Then
            Try
                con.Open()
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete From TB_stinfo where id=?"
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("?", TextBox1.Text))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("one record is deleted")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error while deleting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Delete Records")
            Finally
                dt.Clear()
                Form1_Load(sender, e)
                clear()
                checkcon()
            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("This record is not deleted")
        End If
```

Comment: Start by turning on `Option Strict`, reading [ask], take the [tour], format your code so we can read it, and actually ask a question

Comment: Hint: (1) `MsgBox()` does not return a string, it returns [MsgBoxResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.msgboxresult(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), (2) `if vbyes then` means `if 6 then`, you need an actual conditional in there.

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted your code so it was more readable:

```
Dim deleteok As String = MsgBox("Do you really want to delete this record", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "updating records") 
If vbYes Then 
    Try 
        con.Open() 
        cmd.Connection = con cmd.CommandText = "Delete From TB_stinfo where id=?" 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("?", TextBox1.Text)) 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
        MessageBox.Show("one record is deleted") 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        MessageBox.Show("Error while deleting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Delete Records") 
    Finally 
        dt.Clear() 
        Form1_Load(sender, e) 
        clear() 
        checkcon() 
    End Try 
Else 
    MsgBox("This record is not deleted") 
End If
```

The number one issue I see here is that we do not see what the value of the key is you're deleting on , nor the format of the data that's in the table to delete from. It's impossible to determine what exactly is wrong from this code.

My suggestion is to set a breakpoint on this line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and see what the value of TextBox1.Text is and make sure it is what you expect it to be, look for leading/trailing spaces or anything else that's unexpected..  Other than that there isn't much else to go on here in terms of context.